After changing http -> https -> http, I cannot access admin dashboard
After changing http -> https -> http, I cannot access admin dashboard.
Also I cannot access the server by ftp or ssh.
What should I do?
The site url is
http://biomath.khu.ac.kr

how did you change the http to https? Did you set up an SSL certificate on your server before you did this? Without SSH or FTP access it might not be possible to fix this, especially if you did this via HTAccess files

Thanks for your answer. I changed it through local access. Can I fix it through local access?

I'm not sure what you mean by local access, if you have a local dev environment you can fix your local copy but not the remote server other people see

Thanks! then how can I solve this problem SSH or FTP access? I will try finding way to access through SSH or FTP

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
